# Is there any simple interpretation of $y^TA$ multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have $A$ matrix and $y = Ax$.

If $A$ is orthogonal, then $y^TA=(A^Ty)^T=(A^{-1}y)^T=x^T$.
Is there any simple interpretation of $y^TA$ if $A$ is not orthogonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to impart some other special condition (symmetry, say): it's the linear combination of the rows of $A$ given by the entries of $y$. Similarly $Ax$ is the linear combination of the columns of $A$ given by the entries of $x$. This is about all that can be said in total generality. Some nice things can be said in model contexts: for example, you might want to look at the discussion about electricity in Gilbert Strang's book, where he talks about the Four Fundamental Subspaces.